# Login to android app without using AWS SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an api where I want users to login to AWS cognito but I don't want to force app developers to use the android aws sdk.  How can I do that?  I'm guessing there is an api that Cognito has but I'm not sure what that would be?  I have looked at the aws android docs but they focus on the use of the sdk.

Comment: What you have tried so far, what docs you have using. Login into what.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-using-android-sdk.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html Is there a reason why you don't want to use the SDK? The SDK provides you the low-level interface for the Cognito REST API and a high-level client that solves the common use cases in authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login without any rest api. then you must try the local database like sqlite.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";

private SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase;
private Context mContext;

/*Constructor call when you initialize  DataBasseHelper class*/
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DataBaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, DataBaseConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

/*onCreate Method is used to create table */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "call onCreate");

    db.execSQL("create table userInfo (id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, email text NOT NULL,password text NOT NULL, createdDate text NOT NULL)");

}

/*onUpgrade Method call when database version changed,
that time exsting table delete and new table create.
when we want new table create that time onCreate method will use.*/
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "call onUpgrade");
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + "tableName");

        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/*onCopydatabase Method is used to copy existing database*/
public boolean onCopyDatabase(Context context) {
    Logger.e(TAG, "call onCopyDatabase");
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DataBaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME);
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DataBaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

        String outFileName = dbPath + "/" + DataBaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME;
        Logger.e(TAG, "Database path is : " + outFileName);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w(TAG, "DataBase copied");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: need to authenticate for using api

Comment: @user1584120   when user call api, that time pass header in side the api call. header contain some operation of data those we are pass in parameter with current time. and same proce you can do on api side, when request receive then collect all header and its parameter, same operation you can do own side, if requester and your header match then return response.